# An install problem about BIM Server. How to solve java.lang.NullPointerException: null?

Tags: java

When I install BIM Server, I find a question about Java. Code as follow:

```
14:41:35 ERROR [main]:                                                                                  (JarBimServer.java:163) 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.bimserver.BimServer.start(BimServer.java:808)
    at org.bimserver.JarBimServer.start(JarBimServer.java:160)
    at org.bimserver.JarBimServer.main(JarBimServer.java:79)
```

I know the "java.lang.NullPointerException: null" is a common question, but I dont know how to solve it in the install process.

Comment: I took a brief look at the source code, and I think that you'll have to run this through a debugger to find the root cause. Note to the developers: don't put 500 lines of code in a `try {} catch(Throwable t) {}` block :)

Comment: Thank you！I plan to send a link to this post directly to the development team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in BIMServer to me.  If I have read the code and stacktrace correctly, the BIMServer constructor appears to be (incorrectly) recovering from some initialization problem without setting the LOGGER.  The calling code then attempts to call `start()` which fails, and triggers an NPE because it uses a `null` logger to log the problem.

My advice would be to report this to the maintainers via their issue tracker, giving the evidence (the stacktrace), the exact version that you used, and everything else they will need to reproduce the problem.

Comment: OK. It seems a developer problem, not my fault. Because of my weak programming skills, I plan to send a link to this post directly to the development team.

Thanks again for your suggestions and checks!

Comment: Actually, the logger is used after its initalization, in the `BimServer` constructor. The NPE appears later during `BimServer.start()` execution and likely due to `serverInfoManager` being null. There should likely be something in the logs about its creation. Unfortunately this  has not been posted to the BIMServer issue tracker.